# Publish library for use it with Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When you want to use a library from GitHub that the owner tells you to copy something like this to your dependencies and then you have access to it:

```
compile 'com.1gravity:android-rteditor:1.6.2'
```

How can I make this kind of URL for my library?

Comment: Have you [created a repo](https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo/)?

Comment: Yes I have created the repo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to publish to some public library repositories like `jcenter`, `Maven Central` or `jitpack`.